# Problem with CORS loading data from cakephp restapi implementation into angular app

Tags: php, angular, rest, cors

I'm trying to comunicate with an already working RestAPI server developed in PHP (CakePHP framework); i'm trying to make a simple login action in Angular 7 application and if success i will proceed with the implementations.

This is the Angular App call code:

```
  constructor(protected cli: HttpClient) { 
    this.tablet_couple = new TabletCoupleModule();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cli.get('http://work.local/grai/api-angular/api/v1/tablet_couples/1.json')
    .subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data) }
    )
    this.cli.post('http://work.local/grai/api-angular/api/v1/tablet_couples/login.json',{
      username: 'xxxxxxxx',
      passoword:  '123456789',
    })
    .subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data) }
    )
  }
```

The actual problem is that the `GET` call work fine, but the `POST` call still no working.

I'm sure the REST API is working correctly because if i use tool like Insomnia the response is correct for both calls.

I try to find why but the problem is every time the CORS implementation:

[image]

I have try to force headers in Cakephp as you can see above but still not working.

```
    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        if($this->request->is('OPTIONS')) {
            $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
            $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
            $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Authorization');
        }
        else {
            $this->response = $this->response->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
            $this->response = $this->response->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            $this->response = $this->response->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","*");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

I had find a library to integrate CORS with cakephp : [cakephp-cors](https://github.com/ozee31/cakephp-cors)

This help but i still have a problem: i can't use Rest API if they are not on the same domain (ok is CORS) but i need.

IF i deploy the application and put my Angular App on the same domain it works; but i want deploy app that can access remote REST API.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are getting a 404 response to the OPTIONS request, which likely means it doesn’t get properly routed to begin with.

Comment: @04FS any suggestion to manage an OPTIONS ?

Comment: You should have an all-catch route (a route which gets accepted for any url) for all OPTIONS requests which respond with the Access-Control headers. Also reply with the same Access-Control headers on any request type or else the OPTIONS request will succeed, but the actual POST/GET request will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i had a "solution" tanks to the @JensV.

**1th :: cakephp 3.1.x is too old**

I'm using an OLD version of CakePHP (3.1.14); the 3.1.x is simply too old to manager correctly an OPTIONS Method Call.

Using CakePHP 3.7.* with the plugin [cakephp-cors](https://github.com/ozee31/cakephp-cors) it works correctly and now i can make remote call from localhost:4200 .

**2nd :: the Method OPTIONS**

This is a method that give me so much pain; this method is called by browsers before a POST method call.

The correct response at this method is a HTTP Code 200 from the server.

If you don't manage this call correctly the browser truncate the POST call.

Again i post some reference about this call and how to find a solution:

- [CakePHP, preflight & CORS](https://oskar1233.github.io/2018/02/15/cakephp-preflight-cors.html)
- [Handling “XMLHttpRequest” OPTIONS Pre-flight Request in Laravel](https://medium.com/@neo/handling-xmlhttprequest-options-pre-flight-request-in-laravel-a4c4322051b9)

I hope it helps someone.